# `subject': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError) Using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, specifications

I'm simply trying to test my user model.

The error comes from testing this bit.

```
describe User do
  before do 
    @user = User.new(email: "foo@bar.com", password:"foobar",
                 password_confirmation:"foobar", goal:"cut")
  end

  subject( @user )    
  .
  .
  .
```

Here is the exact error:

```
rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/subject.rb:180:in `subject': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rspec 2.10.1, subject() does not allow for any arguments. See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/2.10.1/RSpec/Core/Subject/ExampleGroupMethods#subject-instance_method

I believe you actually want to pass @user as a block, so:

```
subject{ @user }
```

Notice the {} instead of ().

Comment: Thanks! I guess this question wasn't particularly useful since it's a typo mistake. Oh well.